# AWK - search for something between two sets of chars and display what is inside those two

Tags: bash, unix, awk

As the title says i have a txt file where i keep certain notes and "how to"s. I would combine this with a bash alias function to make a quick search command.For example

```
{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}

{{
How to unmount usb:
sudo umount
```

So if i searched for "How to reboot" i would get:

```
{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}
```

i already have this:

> awk '/{{/,/}}/' *.txt

but i am not sure how to make it display the whole segment. I would put a variable inside so i could pass it arguments with my bash alias like:

```
searchnotes(){
     awk '/regexstuffetcetc $1/' *.txt
}
alias searchnotes=searchnotes
```

but i only need to figure out the awk parameters. Hints or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your records are separated with one or more empty lines

```
$ awk -v RS= -v search='How to reboot' '$0~search' file

{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}
```

if you want to write a function, perhaps something like this

```
$ function search { awk -v RS= -v search="$1" '$0~search' $2; }
$ search "How to reboot" file

{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}
```

if your file is not in paragraph format, you can try this (requires multi-char RS support, i.e. gawk)

```
$ awk -v RS='}}' -v search='How to reboot' '$0~search{print $0 RT}' file
```

Comment: sadly that does not work,  i tried awk -v RS= -v search='How to reboot' '$0~search' *.txt and it did not work. no output. any specifik awk version you are using or distribution?

Comment: does it return any lines without `-v RS=`?

Comment: tried "awk -v search='How to reboot' "$0~search" *.txt"  and no luck

Comment: that means either your `awk` is really broken or your text doesn't include that string.  It should be single quotes though!  I'm guessing it's a typo.

Comment: i have GNU awk 4.0.1 and yes, im using single quotes. what awk do you have?  EDIT: nevermind , it works! thank you.  tried again and it worked, not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat program.awk                      # looks cryptic
/{{/ { if(f==1) print b; b=""; f="" }  # at begin marker print if flag up and clean
$0 ~ s { f=1 }                         # if keyword found, flag up
{ b=b $0 ORS }                         # gather buffer
END { if(f==1) print b }               # if no end marker found but flag up print
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -v s="sudo" -f program.awk file
{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}

{{
How to unmount usb:
sudo umount
```

Apparently regex works also:

```
$ awk -v s="How.*reb" -f program.awk file
{{
How to reboot:
sudo reboot
}}
```

Comment: works great, nicely done :) have to lookup what all the switches do. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can buffer the lines between `{{` and `}}` and then check if they match your keyword, in sed one can do:

```
sed -n '/{{/{  # Match {{
  :s;          # Define label 's'
  N;           # Append next line to pattern space
  /}}/{        # Match }}
    /reboot/p; # Match 'reboot' and print all buffered lines
    be         # Goto 'e'
  };
  bs;          # Goto 's'
};
:e             # Define label 'e'
' input.txt    # Input file(s)
```

And in AWK it can look like this:

```
awk '/{{/,/}}/ {
  buff = buff $0 RS;
  if (/}}/ && buff ~ /reboot/) {
    printf "%s", buff;
  }
  next;
}
{ buff = "" }'
```

Comment: i tried your soliton by trying "awk -v s="wifi" -f wk.awk *.txt" but i get no output, how did you run it? i copied all of the stuff inside the  " ' " single quotes